# Can I use CSP to limit requests to both https: AND 'self'?

Tags: security, http, https, http-headers, content-security-policy

I originally had this in my CSP header: `default-src 'self';`, which limits sources to only my domain, but it says nothing about the scheme/protocol. From what I can gather, this will allow sources to be loaded over http if the page itself was loaded over http. I'm using HSTS and CDN redirects to try to keep all traffic on https, but I want to cover this case off anyway. (In truth, I'm trying to make [this header checker](https://open.srcclr.com/security-headers) give me all green ticks.) **Edit**: srcclr will happily give all green ticks when using `'self'`. I just had to fix some typos.

Anyway, I tried changing the CSP directive to be `default-src https: 'self';`, but it would seem that adding the scheme allows resources to be loaded from *any* domain, as long as it's over https. I.e, if either of the rules (https or 'self') matches, then the request is allowed. I tested this by playing around with URLs in the chrome dev tools.

Is there a way to indicate:

1. All resources should be loaded over https; AND
2. Resources should only come from the original domain?

Something like `default-src https://'self';`, but I don't think that's valid, is it?

One solution is to hardcode the domain name, but I'd like to use `'self'` if it's possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/Sources, the `'self'` content source keyword:

> Refers to the origin from which the protected document is being served, including the same URL scheme and port number.

If you serve the web page over https, then self only allow **https** request to the same domain.

The CSP2 specification http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#match-source-expression says the same thing:

> If the source expression is a case insensitive match for 'self' (including the quotation marks), then:
>
> Return does match if the origin of url matches the origin of protected resource’s URL.

Comment: Right, so I guess it's not possible to say "the domain from `'self'`, but this specific scheme". If the page is served on http, then by definition `'self'` refers to http. So the only way to fix it to both https and my own domain, would be to use `https://example.com`.

Comment: @CamJackson I don't understand. You say the page with the CSP use http ? But you said your domain use HSTS. (Note that 301 redirect for http->https do not need CSP.) If you really use HSTS, you should answer a 301 to https for all http request, as new browser will do it automatically

Comment: No, I'm saying that ***if*** the page were to be served over http, then `'self'` would also refer to http, so the only way to always limit to https, while also limiting to my domain only, is to hardcode `https://example.com`, rather than using `'self'`. I think that's how it works? But yes, I'm using redirects and HSTS to limit page loads to https anyway, so using `'self'` is the simpler and better solution. Mostly I was trying to get all green ticks from srcclr. (Which I've now done, I just had to fix some typos)

Comment: Source does not contain the quote you're referencing, do you have an updated link?

Comment: Updated with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/Sources